# Objective-c How to do validation on textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, uitextfield

I would like to prevent the user from not entering any data as well as entering only spaces. So basically there must at least be one character without a space. Then I would also like to remove any spaces at the beginning of the word so the first letter is a character that is not a space.

**edit**

the user must enter something and if the user enters a few spaces before it then I want to trim those spaces. I also want to prevent the user from just entering spaces.

**Example**

if the user enter's a name and surname like " James Dean" I would like to take the first space away but not the second space between James and Dean.

Comment: [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:<#(NSCharacterSet *)#>]

Comment: for more go for regular expressions

Comment: what you want exactly?you want to enter the string which is not having the first letter as a space am i right?

Comment: the user must enter something and if the user enters a few spaces before it then I want to trim those spaces. I also want to prevent the user from just entering spaces.

Comment: you wants to trim the string after entering data in textfield (or) you want to restrict the user for not entering the space as a text?

Comment: try with my code it won't accepts the first letter as space after the first letter it'l accepts the space.

Comment: I want to trim afterwards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set your `UIViewController` to be your destination `UITextField`'s `delegate` and implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

  // verify the text field you wanna validate
  if (textField == _nameTextField) {

    // do not allow the first character to be space | do not allow more than one space
    if ([string isEqualToString:@" "]) {
      if (!textField.text.length)
        return NO;
      if ([[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] rangeOfString:@"  "].length)
        return NO;
    }

    // allow backspace
    if ([textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length < textField.text.length) {
      return YES;
    }

    // in case you need to limit the max number of characters
    if ([textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length > 30) {
      return NO;
    }

    // limit the input to only the stuff in this character set, so no emoji or cirylic or any other insane characters
    NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "];

    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound) {
      return NO;
    }

  }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Superb..!! Saved my day (Y)

Comment: CAUTION: characterSetWithCharactersInString example does not include letters used in languages other than English. For example, if you have European users, they may enter letters with diacritic marks above them. Rejecting those is probably not acceptable outside of English locales. As a minimum, replace such a letter with the "plain" version (the letter without the mark). That isn't really acceptable, but is less obnoxious   than throwing away the letter.

Answer (score 5):

try like this may be it helps to you,here is my code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 

    replacementString:(NSString *)string{
        if([text.text length]==0){
        if([string isEqualToString:@" "]){
            return NO;
        }
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

By placing this code user won't enter space as a first letter but it accepts the space in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint for the first part.

```
NSString *tempname1 = [self.textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

BOOL thereAreJustSpaces = [tempname1 isEqualToString:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working to the point where I must just remove the spaces at the beginning of the word.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)removeSpacesFromTextFields:(id) sender {
    NSString *trim = [self.FNTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if ([trim length] == 0) {
      self.FNTextField.text = @"";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, If you want to prevent space in your text field.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkSpace:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification  object:textfield];

}
 -(void)checkSpace:(NSNotification *)notification
{

  str = [textfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] ;
 textfield.text=str;
}
```

Comment: This obviously will not allow to add any spaces at all

Comment: This is close to what I want to do. But if the user enter's a name and surname like " James Dean" I would like to take the first space away but not the second space between James and Dean.

Comment: @user1898829  for that you can use [txtUserName.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];